# How can I control my direction type preference in the new Google Maps link URLs?

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to be able to have a Google Maps direction link which, when opened on mobile (Android), would bring up directions in Google Maps using a specified direction type (e.g. bicycle).

Using the *old* Google Maps URL parameters you can do,

```
https://www.google.com/maps/preview?saddr=[insert_from_address_here]&daddr=[insert_to_address_here]&dirflg=[insert_mode_here]
```

but it doesn't work on mobile.

Using the *new* Google Maps URL parameters you can do,

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/[customer address]/[our address]/am=t/
```

which does work on mobile but I don't know how to specify direction type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Google Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/4CiQTcarJHk/freuulMVFH0J) itself, try this on your URL if this works.

```
Car /data=!4m2!4m1!3e0
Bicycling /data=!4m2!4m1!3e1
Walking /data=!4m2!4m1!3e2
Public Transit /data=!4m2!4m1!3e3
Airplane /data=!4m2!4m1!3e4
```

For example

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/747+Howard+St,+San+Francisco,+CA/55+Music+Concourse+Dr,+San+Francisco,+CA/data=!4m2!4m1!3e3
```

For more information, juct check the link above and this [stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67190/how-can-i-encode-my-preference-of-biking-walking-public-transport-in-a-google-ma) question.